# Async realtime updates with Firestore issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I try to get realtime data back from Firestore with React-Native.
I have a `helpers.js` file where I store and export all the get and set functions for Firestore and I just import them in `App.js` to use it.

When I try to get only once (no realtime), it works perfectly. 
This is working:

In `helpers.js`:

```
const waitlistRef = db.firestore().collection('waitlist');

export async function getWaitlist() {
  let waitlist = [];

  await waitlistRef.get().then(res => {
      res.forEach(doc => {
      waitlist.push(doc.data());
    });
  });

  return waitlist;
}
```

In `App.js`:

```
import { getWaitlist } from './helpers';

...

useEffect(() => {
 getWaitlist().then(waitlist => console.log(waitlist));
}, []);
```

So it works, but I only can get it once (no realtime). In order to get realtime updates, I've tried this method:

In `helpers.js`:

```
const waitlistRef = db.firestore().collection('waitlist');

export async function getWaitlist() {
  let waitlist = [];

  await waitlistRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(doc =>
      waitlist.push(doc.data()),
    );
  });

  return waitlist;
}
```

In `App.js`:

```
import { getWaitlist } from './helpers';

...

useEffect(() => {
 getWaitlist().then(waitlist => console.log(waitlist));
}, []);
```

But when I try to log the `waitlist` array which was supposed to be returned from the helper function, I just get an empty array.

Any ideas?

Comment: `onSnapshot` does not return a Promise, but attaches a listener and returns "An unsubscribe function that can be called to cancel the snapshot listener" see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.html#onsnapshot

Comment: What do you want to do with the return value rom `getWaitlist()` (in code)? Keep in mind: when you use `onSnapshot` you get the realtime updates to the data too, so your callback function may be called multiple times. Theoretically you could `await` the data the first time and return it, but what do you expect to happen when there's an update?